# LLVM, Get first usage of a global variable

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to LLVM and I'm stuck on something that might seem basic.

I'm writing a LLVM pass to apply some transformations to global variables before they are use.

I would like to detect somehow when is the first usage of a global variable to only apply the transformation there, and not in all places where the global variable is used. But it must be the first time it is used otherwise the program crashes.

I have been reading about the AnalysisManager, and I would say that I want something similar to DominatorTree which is used for basic blocks in a function.

So the idea is to get the DominatorTree of a GlobalVariable to get the first time it is used in the code and apply there my transformation.

Given the following example

```
int MyGlobal = 30;

void foo()
{
    printf("%s\n", MyGlobal);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", MyGlobal);
    foo();
}
```

In the example above, I only want to apply the transformation just before the first printf in the main function

Given the following example

```
int MyGlobal = 30;

void foo()
{
    printf("%s\n", MyGlobal);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    printf("%s\n", MyGlobal);
}
```

For the example above I would like to apply the transformation inside the foo function.

I want to avoid to create a stub function at the beginning of the program to process all globals before start running (This is what actually Im doing)

Does LLVM provide something that can help me doing this? or what should be the best approach to implement it?

Comment: This doesn't sound possible at compile-time. What if `main` did `if (argc == 42) foo(); else printf(....);`? Same thing if foo conditionally accesses the variable.

Comment: Yeah, as per Mat's comment, this would be undecidable to determine runtime usage. An approximate syntactic approach that tries to create an ordering between uses using the dominator tree and call graph could be endeavoured upon, but probably isn't what you want. A simpler method would be to guard accesses with something that does runtime book-keeping. You'd rewrite uses to do this check and only perform your one time operation if some flag is not set, otherwise just use the value. This comes at some cost though, you should determine if it's really necessary to do initialisation dynamically.

Comment: Also remember to consider that you may compile your program to a standalone binary (not a .so/.dylib/.dll), then someone else may "dlopen" (or LoadLibrary) your program and call its external functions in any order they like.

Comment: If you can't establish where the "first" usage is at compile-time (for reasons given in comments above), you may want to consider creating a dynamic check, adding a private "is_MyGlobal_initialized" check to the code each time it's accessed. Put another way, there's a reason we use https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-global-ctors-global-variable

Comment: "DominatorTree of a GlobalVariable" There's no such thing-- a dominator tree is computed from the control-flow graph (CFG), the graph of where the instruction pointer goes in a function. In LLVM, you can see the CFG as part of the function, starting at entry block and branching to later blocks. Global variables don't have a CFG, they aren't moving the instruction pointer around. In LLVM you can compute a dominator tree of a function, in theory you may also being to compute a dominator tree of any graph including a function call graph (but indirect calls like C++ virtual calls won't work).

Comment: What you ask for isn't generally possible, as other comments point out. However, if you restrain yourself to a subset, something like it is possible. Are you looking for the general (and impossible) case, or for some special case or subset? Detecting first usages of a few ELF-private globals is possible if you specify what to do about undecidable cases, so if you clarify your question an answer might be possible.